# Update2,Haskell

Tags: haskell

1. Atom: The Atom is the datatype used to describe Atomic Sentences or propositions. These are basically
   represented as a string.
2. Literal: Literals correspond to either atoms or negations of atoms. In this implementation each literal
   is represented as a pair consisting of a boolean value, indicating the polarity of the Atom, and the
   actual Atom. Thus, the literal ‘P’ is represented as (True,"P") whereas its negation ‘-P’ as
   (False,"P").
   2
3. Clause: A Clause is a disjunction of literals, for example PvQvRv-S. In this implementation this
   is represented as a list of Literals. So the last clause would be [(True,"P"), (True,"Q"),
   (True,"R"),(False,"S")].
4. Formula: A Formula is a conjunction of clauses, for example (P vQ)^(RvP v-Q)^(-P v-R).
   This is the CNF form of a propositional formula. In this implementation this is represented as a list of
   Clauses, so it is a list of lists of Literals. Our above example formula would be [[(True,"P"),
   (True,"Q")], [(True,"R"), (True,"P"), (False,"Q")], [(False, "P"),
   (False,"P")]].
5. Model: A (partial) Model is a (partial) assignment of truth values to the Atoms in a Formula. In this
   implementation this is a list of (Atom, Bool) pairs, ie. the Atoms with their assignments. So in the
   above example of type Formula if we assigned true to P and false to Q then our model would be
   [("P", True),("Q", False)]

Ok so I wrote and update function

```
       update :: Node -> [Node]
```

It takes in a Node and returns a list of the Nodes
that result from assigning True to an unassigned atom in one case and False in the other (ie. a case
split). The list returned has two nodes as elements. One node  contains the formula
with an atom assigned True and the model updated with this assignment, and the other contains
the formula with the atom assigned False and the model updated to show this. The lists of unassigned
atoms of each node are also  updated accordingly. This function makes use  of an 
assign function to make the assignments. It also uses the chooseAtom function  to
select the literal to assign.

```
    update :: Node -> [Node]
    update (formula, (atoms, model)) = [(assign (chooseAtom atoms, True) formula, (remove (chooseAtom atoms) atoms, ((chooseAtom atoms,True)) `insert` model)) , (assign (chooseAtom atoms, False) formula, (remove (chooseAtom atoms) atoms, ((chooseAtom atoms, False) `insert` model)) )]
```

Now I have to do the same thing but this time I must  implement a variable selection heuristic.this should replace the chooseAtom and I'm supposed to write a function update2 using it

```
    type Atom = String
    type Literal = (Bool,Atom)
    type Clause = [Literal]  
    type Formula = [Clause]
    type Model = [(Atom, Bool)]
    type Node = (Formula, ([Atom], Model))
   update2 :: Node -> [Node]
   update2 = undefined
```

So my question is how can I create a heurestic and to implement it into the update2 function ,that shoud behave identical to the update function ?

Comment: What is this about? What are your `Node`, `Atom`, `Literal` and other types meant to represent?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a Haskell question. You know how to write functions in Haskell. What you don't know is how to write a function that implements a variable selection heuristic. Neither do we: it is not part of Haskell, it is part of your problem domain.

Comment: I wrote as concise as possible....should I add other details?My main concern is writting the heurestic,because this is all the info that I have....so if you find the problem ambiguous then now you know why I asked for help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you're asking how to implement additional selection rules in resolution systems for propositional logic. Presumably, you're constructing a tree of formulas gotten by assigning truth-values to literals until either (a) all possible combinations of assignments to literals have been tried or (b) box (the empty clause) has been derived.

Assuming the function *chooseAtom* implements a selection rule, you can parameterize the function *update* over an arbitrary selection rule *r* by giving *update* an additional parameter and replacing the occurrence of *chooseAtom* in *update* by *r*. Since *chooseAtom* implements a selection rule, passing that selection rule to the parameter *r* gives the desired result. If you provide an implementation of *chooseAtom* and the function you intend to replace it, it would be easier to verify that your implementation is correct.

Hopefully this is helpful. However, it's unclear exactly what's being asked. In particular, you're asking for a "variable selection rule." However, it looks like you're implementing a resolution system for propositional logic. In general, selection rules and variables are associated with resolution for predicate logic.